# ¿ Por qué no obtengo el usuario indicado desde Angular y Nodejs?

Tags: nodejs, angular, rest

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un `input text` donde introduzco el username del cliente, el resultado debería mostrarlo en la tabla. Pero no me devuelve nada. El servidor esta funcionando bien, porque cuando hago La `solicitudes Rest` con  `insomnia` me devuelve el resultado. Pero en `Angular` no se refleja nada.

Aca `index.controller.ts` de `Nodejs` donde tengo la función para obtener el usuario por username:

```js
export const getUserByUserName = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
    const response: QueryResult = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1', [req.params.username]);
    return res.json(response.rows);   
}
```

Desde `Angular` tengo la `clase userService` donde implemento la función:

```js
URL_API = 'http://localhost:4000/users';

userArray: User[]; // array de tipo User

getUserByUserName(username: string) {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.URL_API}/${username}`);
  }
```

Aca el componente `clients.component.ts` de `Angular`

```js
inputValue: string;

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
  }

getUserByUserName(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
    this.userService.getUserByUserName(form.value).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.userService.userArray = res;
      },
      err => console.error(err) // si hay error, mostralo en consola
    );
  }
  
  
    getUsers() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      // la resuesta guardala en el array userArray declarado en userService
      res => {
        this.userService.userArray = res;
      },
      err => console.error(err) // si hay error, mostralo en consola
    );
  }
```

y aca la vista `clients.component.html`

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2>Sección clientes</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form #searchForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="getUserByUserName(searchForm)" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Nombre de usuario del cliente" 
                aria-label="Search" [(ngModel)]="inputValue">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h5 class="text-center">Lista de clientes</h5>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center"></td>
                        <th class="text-center">Usuario</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Email</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Nombre</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Apellido</th>
                        <td class="text-center"></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let u of userService.userArray; index as i">
                        <td class="text-center">{{ i + 1 }}</td>                        
                        <td class="text-center"> {{ u.username }} </td>
                        <td class="text-center"> {{ u.email }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center"> {{ u.name }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center"> {{ u.surname }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">       
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md mr-1">Ventas</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-md">Perfil</button>                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu búsqueda envías un `form.value`, y tu input de búsqueda lo tienes bindeado a una variable `inputValue`, tienes que enviar esa variable a tu servicio.

```
getUserByUserName(form: NgForm) {
    this.userService.getUserByUserName(inputValue).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.userService.userArray = res;
      },
      err => console.error(err) // si hay error, mostralo en consola
    );
  }
```

Y si lo que quieres es obtenerlo de tu `NgForm` tienes que obtener esa propiedad. ya que dentro de el `value` viene una propiedad `search` que corresponde a tu input con su valor.

```
getUserByUserName(form: NgForm) {
    this.userService.getUserByUserName(form.value.search).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.userService.userArray = res;
      },
      err => console.error(err) // si hay error, mostralo en consola
    );
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, justo iba a publicar mi respuesta, que habia encontrado la solucion. Tenia la variable inputValue al input y era esa variable la que tenia que poner en mi funcion como tu lo has dicho. Gracia por tu aclaracion sobre el form.value.search como parametro en la funcion, era eso lo que tmb estaba intentando hacer en un principio y no sabia como hacerlo ya que estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Angular.